# Linq : mapping pro to function with 2 different statement

Tags: sql, linq

I make stored procedure that select data with condition but the problem is :-

when RequiredIDID =2  ( Select come with some data from join table and if not I am not select it in else statement ) and after mapping to linq function this problem appears

if I'm pass requirdID = 2 to function no problem occurs coz the first select in proc executed but if I pass other requirdID ( ex. = 3 ) this message appears

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'RealEstateCenterModel.SearchForRealState_Reader'. A member of the
>   type, 'FloorTypeCategory', does not have a corresponding column in the
>   data reader with the same name.

```
USE [RealEstateCenter]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TestOptionalParameter]    Script Date: 08/23/2012 07:29:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[TestOptionalParameter]
@RequiredIDID int =NULL 
as

if @RequiredIDID=2
begin
SELECT     FloorSpace.SpaceFrom, RealEstateCategoryDetails.RequiredCategoryTypeName, FloorType.FloorTypeCategory, FloorType.FloorNotes, 
                      RealEstateTypes.RequiedType
FROM         PersonalRealStateDetails INNER JOIN
                      FloorSpace ON PersonalRealStateDetails.FloorSpaceID = FloorSpace.FloorSpaceID INNER JOIN
                      RealEstateCategoryDetails ON PersonalRealStateDetails.RequiredCategoryTypeID = RealEstateCategoryDetails.RequiredCategoryTypeID INNER JOIN
                      FloorType ON PersonalRealStateDetails.FloorTypeID = FloorType.FloorTypeID INNER JOIN
                      RealEstateTypes ON RealEstateCategoryDetails.RequiredID = RealEstateTypes.RequiredID

end

else
begin
SELECT     FloorSpace.SpaceFrom, RealEstateCategoryDetails.RequiredCategoryTypeName, RealEstateTypes.RequiedType
FROM         PersonalRealStateDetails INNER JOIN
                      FloorSpace ON PersonalRealStateDetails.FloorSpaceID = FloorSpace.FloorSpaceID INNER JOIN
                      RealEstateCategoryDetails ON PersonalRealStateDetails.RequiredCategoryTypeID = RealEstateCategoryDetails.RequiredCategoryTypeID INNER JOIN
                      RealEstateTypes ON RealEstateCategoryDetails.RequiredID = RealEstateTypes.RequiredID
end
```

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the missing columns, with some default values, to the second select.

```
SELECT FloorSpace.SpaceFrom, RealEstateCategoryDetails.RequiredCategoryTypeName, RealEstateTypes.RequiedType, 0 as [FloorType.FloorTypeCategory], NULL as [FloorType.FloorNotes]
```

or

```
SELECT FloorSpace.SpaceFrom, RealEstateCategoryDetails.RequiredCategoryTypeName, RealEstateTypes.RequiedType, 0 as FloorTypeCategory, NULL as FloorNotes
```

Comment: But it gave me error in syntax 
NULL as FloorType.FloorTypeCategory,

Comment: i am set it as the following :-

but coz their is a join some data not come in they query